# Where can I find visual studio macro examples?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, macros

When I look up anything about macros for Visual studio 2005, everyone is referencing the samples that ship with it.  However, Visual studio was installed for me (IT department) and I do not have these sample macros.

Is there another place I can find(or download) them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can also create your own using the macro recorder (Ctrl+Shift+R).   After you record some actions, stop recording (ctrl+shift+R again), you can view the macro source using the Macros IDE (Tools | Macros | Macros IDE).

Answer (score 0):

In VC 6 they used to be in a normal file from what I remember, but I'm not sure where they are kept in VS2005 and VS2008. I can't imagine that there is an install option to *not* include them.

Did you look in the Macro IDE or the Macro Explorer?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2shw615(VS.80).aspx

> The Macros IDE includes some sample macros for your study and use. They are located in a node called Samples and are available in either the Macro Explorer or the Macros IDE. The following is a list of the macro samples and a description of what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Try here for examples and tutorials

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/)

[Line Counter Add-in](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx)